# Primes of the form $a k + b$: Which infinite?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> ***Q***. For which integers $a$ and $b$ is it known that there are
> an infinite number of primes of the form $a k + b$?

Can you extend this list?
Is it known whether the length of the list is finite or infinite?
\begin{align}
& 4 k + 3 \\
& 6 k + 1 \\
& \cdots
\end{align}

Comment: [Dirichlet's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) covers this.

Comment: @lulu: Thanks, that answers my question!

Comment: Necessary and sufficient is that $a$ and $b$ are coprime. Hence the list is infinite.